# displaying data in table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

table is not displaying any value in table. When i did var_dump($results). It printed NULL. Since, i am new to codeigniter, i am not able to solve this problem. 
I'm not getting, where i did mistake. Help Me.

View Page

```
 <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($results) ) {
                        foreach($results as $row) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'." ".'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row->FileTitle.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row->UploadedFile.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row->CreationDate.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row->UpdateDate.'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'." ".'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        }
                    }?>
                </tbody>
```

Controller

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('news_model');

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        }
public function member_CAttachments()
    {
         $data['results'] = $this->news_model->member_MAttachments(); 
         $this->load->view('member/templates/header');
         $this->load->view('member/index',$data);
         $this->load->view('member/templates/footer');
        }
}
```

Model

```
class News_model extends CI_Model 
{

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }
     public function member_MAttachments()
    {
        $results = array();

            $query = $this->db->get('MemberFileDetails');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
                $results = $query->result();
            }

            return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are not getting any result from your query!!check result present in your database or not!!

Comment: remove $results = array();. its just a suggestion. try it.

Comment: $data['results'] print in controller and check that you are getting any result or not also $query->num_rows() print it

Comment: Also if no result found return false

Comment: @syedmohamed: yeah. thank you. got it. Sorry all, i wasted all your time. In url, some different view was getting called. i didn't saw that. Just now, i discovered it. 
i changed to http://localhost/Project/index.php/welcome/member_CAttachments
Previously it was
http://localhost/Project/index.php/welcome/check_login
So, i changed code their in check_login controller. I made it redirect to this page. Thank You Everyone. Sorry For Wasting all your important time. Embarass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can do it in fewer lines with inbuilt [`CI Table`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html) library,

supports both `2.2` and `3.x` versions.

Use it like,

```
$this->load->library('table');

$this->table->set_heading('FileTitle', 'UploadedFile', 'CreationDate', 'UpdateDate');

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM MemberFileDetails');

echo $this->table->generate($query);
```

Comment: Wow. Is it. Nice. Let me use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you have records in your table ? if yes then please try to remove the

`if($query->num_rows() > 0)`  condition in the model and try.

Answer (score 0):

remove `$results = array();` in your code